# How to delete an item from an array (along with the 'Delete' button that next to it)? REACT

Tags: reactjs

I  made a list. And I want there to be a button that deletes an unwanted line from the list. The button does not work. Thanks in advance

```
function App() {

  const [val,setval]=useState('enter please');
  const [enter,setenter]=useState([]);

function handle(){ 
   if (val!==''){setenter([...enter,val])
setval('')}
}
function delet(e){ /// here is the problem!!
//var indexi= e.target.id;
if(e>-1){ enter.splice(e,1)}
setenter(enter);
}
function handval(e){
  setval(e.target.value)
}
  return (
    <div >
 
  <input type="text"  onChange={handval}  value={val}  ></input>
  <button onClick={handle}> click </button>
  {enter.map(index => (<li>{index} ,
  <button id={index} on onClick={delet(index)}>delete</button></li>  ))}
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What line does your button want to delete? We need more details.

Comment: Next to each row that is added to the array (by 'input') there is a 'delete' button to delete this line. I have fixed to () => still the button  'delete' does not delete the row next to it

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick handler you are essentially calling `delet(index)`, rather than passing it to be called when the event is triggered. To solve this, simply change the onClick handler to
`onClick={() => delet(index)}`

Comment: Next to each row that is added to the array (by 'input') there is a 'delete' button to delete this line. I have fixed to () => still the button  'delete' does not delete the row next to it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a `key` when using `map`

```js
enter.map(index => (<li key={index}> ...
```

Then, in your `enter` array you have **values** typped in your input, and not an index.
So your `enter.splice(e,1)` is nonsense because `e` is not a number, but a string.

If you need the 'map' index, you should use

```js
enter.map((value, index) => (....)
```

Comment: O.K... but what is the problem?
function delet(e){
if(Number(e)>-1){ enter.splice(Number(e),1)}
setenter(enter);
}-----------------------
{enter.map((enter,index) => (<li key={index}> {enter},
  <button id={index} on onClick={()=>delet(index)}>delete</button>
  </li>  ))}